# Amazon API to get my cart items and previous orders

Tags: amazon-product-api

Does Amazon provide any API to get my cart items and order details, this is for my personal use. I tried  searching but found only seller account API's. I'm not a amazon seller, so my question is does amazon provide API for customers? And is consuming seller account API free of cost and does it have end points to get my cart items and orders?

Answer (score 1):

There's no API to retrieve your personal -customer- shopping cart contents or orders. There isn't any seller/associate API that grants access to carts/orders either.

You could scrape your cart page's HTML to get around it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a GET request to `https://www.amazon.com/cart`

From that page's source, each cart item is contained in a div with a `data-asin` attribute. The value of the `data-asin` is the ASIN, which is a unique number assigned to every product on Amazon. That div tag also has attributes like `data-price` and `data-quantity` (which are equal to price and quantity, respectively).

This jQuery code will get all the divs with the `data-asin` attribute:

`$('div[data-asin]')`

Here's some example code that prints the price of each item in the console:

```
$('div[data-asin]').each(function(){
    var price = $(this).attr("data-price");
    console.log("Price: $" + price);
});
```

If you need more information like the title, that's a child of the div. You can get that with a selector or XPath, etc.

Comment: So the only way to do it is to login manually with user+password and scrape the data?